# Magento 1.9 : How can i filter specific state inside foreach with Observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, filter, shipping-address

How can I add if the condition for my for each loop,

my_observer :

```
<?php
    class Gta_GetOrderDetails_Model_Observer
    {
        public function getdetailsafterorder($Observer)
        {
            $order = $Observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $items = $order->getAllItems();
            $shipping_state = $Observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getShippingAddress();
            if($shipping_state()->getRegion() == 'Kerala')
                {
                    foreach($items as $item)
                    {
                        $sku = $item->getSku();
                        $name= $item->getName();
                        $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
                        $price = $item->getPrice();
                        $shipping_state = $Observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getShippingAddress();
                        $loggerInfo = ['sku' => $sku, 'name' => $name, 'qty' => $qty, 'price' => $price];
                        Mage::log(json_encode(print_r($loggerInfo, true)), null, 'event.log', true);
                    }
                }
            ### start test observer ###
            // $order = $Observer->getEvent();
            // Mage::log($order->getName(),null,'event.log');
             ### end test observer ###
        } 
    } 
?>
```

I just want to add shipping state as my filter.

Comment: what condition you want ?

Comment: If order placed  get selected fields like sku,name,qty_ordered,Price and put into my_log.log file in var/log section,   here how can i add condition like if order from kerala log not to be create.

Comment: I mean log create only for state Kerala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this:**

```
foreach($items as $item)
            {
                $sku = $item->getSku();
                $name= $item->getName();
                $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
                $price = $item->getPrice();
                $shipping_state = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getRegion()

                if($shipping_state == "Kerala") // only state match 'KERALA' when create log file
                {

                    $loggerInfo = ['sku' => $sku, 'name' => $name, 'qty' => $qty, 'price' => $price];
                    Mage::log(json_encode(print_r($loggerInfo, true)), null, 'event.log', true);
                }

            }
```

Comment: Its working, Thank you

Comment: In $loggerInfo how can i add state? i just tried this not working :  $loggerInfo = ['sku' => $sku, 'name' => $name, 'qty' => $qty, 'price' => $price, 'shipping_state' => $shipping_state ];

Comment: please up vote answer it help to find solutions others

Comment: you need to add shipping state in log ?

Comment: yes, i need that also

Comment: $loggerInfo = ['sku' => $sku, 'name' => $name, 'qty' => $qty, 'price' => $price, 'shipping_state' => $shipping_state ];  its not working

Comment: $loggerInfo = [
    'sku' => $sku,
    'name' => $name,
    'qty' => $qty, 
    'price' => $price, 
    'shipping_state' => $shipping_state 
     ];    ********** then run commands also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97761/discussion-between-zus-and-shafeel-sha).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97766/discussion-between-zus-and-shafeel-sha).

Comment: how to add if condition in $emailTemplate->setToEmail('testing@example.com'); my code : https://paste.ofcode.org/TULC7A9K3TywXMvJjnhpsX

Comment: actually what is your requiremnet

Comment: For merchant they should receive mail, if order placed in that order sku start with 2 mail should go abc@gmail.com & if sku start with 3 mail should go xyz@gmail.com & if sku start 4 mail should go qwe@gmail.com

Comment: If order contains all combination of sku, mail should go all mail accounts

Comment: please share the question link

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/300187/57334

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102825/discussion-between-zus-and-dj-dev