# How to send Observer Response via mail?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, mail

My observer :

```
<?php
    class Gta_MerchantNotification_Model_Observer
    {
        public function merchantremainder($Observer)
        {
            $order = $Observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $order_details = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
            foreach ($order_details as $list) {
                $incrementid = $order->getIncrementId();
                $sku = $list->getsku();
                $name = $list->getName();
                $price = $list->getPrice();
                $Qty = $list->getQtyOrdered();


                Mage::log("Id : $incrementid, Sku : $sku, Product name : $name, Price : $price, Qty Ordered : $Qty",  null, 'merchant.log', true);

            }
        }
}

?>
```

Output ;

> Id : 100000083, Sku : #14, Product name : The Step F1004 Step Workout
>   System, Price : 28.5, Qty Ordered : 1

How to send mail?

Comment: I have added my comment below. Please use that and let me know if you are getting any issue.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/300187/82771

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below code.

```
<?php
class Gta_MerchantNotification_Model_Observer
{
    public function merchantremainder($Observer)
    {
        $order = $Observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order_details = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($order_details as $list) {
            $incrementid = $order->getIncrementId();
            $sku = $list->getsku();
            $name = $list->getName();
            $price = $list->getPrice();
            $Qty = $list->getQtyOrdered();

            $message = "Id : ". $incrementid . "Sku : ". $sku . "Product name : ". $name . "Price : " . $price . "Qty Ordered : ". $Qty;
            $this->sendMail($message);
            Mage::log("Id : $incrementid, Sku : $sku, Product name : $name, Price : $price, Qty Ordered : $Qty",  null, 'merchant.log', true);
        }
    }

    public function sendMail($message) 
    {
        $body = "<p>".$message."</p>";
        $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
        $mail->setToName('Your Name');
        $mail->setToEmail('Youe Email');
        $mail->setBody($body);
        $mail->setSubject('Mail Subject');
        $mail->setFromEmail('Sender Mail Id');
        $mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
        $mail->setType('html');// You can use Html or text as Mail format

        try {
            $mail->send();
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please check in log, what error are you getting.

Comment: Unable to send. error

Comment: Can you check Mail is working or not on your server?

Comment: final code : https://paste.ofcode.org/sAkr2mtM96tqhXWTKq9XwY

Comment: Also add this line in catch condition to check exact message.
`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());`

https://paste.ofcode.org/bypShXdJ8n44s7TiJ4qq6g

Comment: mail setting port error, let me solve

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you then please accept this answer.

Comment: Is above code working for you OR did you get any error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102825/discussion-between-zus-and-dj-dev).

Comment: How to add if condition in $mail->setToEmail('Youe Email');

Comment: What you want Exactly? Please let me know?

Comment: If sku contains 22 mail should go abc@gmail.com else if sku contains 33 mail should go xyz@gmail.com else if sku contains 44 mail should go qwe@gmail.com, so that how to add if condition for $mail -> setToEmail()?

Comment: I hope i explained well, any doubt? @DJ Dev

Comment: It means if you have 3 sku (22, 33 and 44 ) in 1 order then 3 mail will trigger, so for this you will need to add send mail function in loop and need to pass one more variable `sku` in that function and then you can add your condition accordingly

Comment: Yes, take a eg, if order contains 3 items like 223345 & 567788 & 343565. My condition if sku start with 2 send mail to abc@gmail.com and if sku start with 5 send mail to xyz@gmail.com and if sku start with 3 send mail to qwe@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to send an email.

```
$body = "Your Response";
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$emailTemplate->setFromName('Your Store Name');
$emailTemplate->setBody($body);
$emailTemplate->setSubject("Custom Email from observer");
$emailTemplate->setType('html');
$emailTemplate->setToEmail('testing@example.com');
$emailTemplate->send();
```